# RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [64, 3, 3, 3], expected input[4, 4, 1024, 2048] to have 3 channels, but got 4 channels instead

Tags: python, image, image-processing, pytorch, torchvision

My model is something like this and designed to work with RGB images. Previously I tested with both RGB and Grayscale images and it was fine. Suddenly it is not working with a new RGB dataset.

```
class UNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(UNet, self).__init__()
        self.inc = inconv(3, 64)
        self.down1 = down(64, 128)
        self.down2 = down(128, 256)
        self.down3 = down(256, 512)
        self.down4 = down(512, 512)
        self.up1 = up(1024, 256)
        self.up2 = up(512, 128)
        self.up3 = up(256, 64)
        self.up4 = up(128, 64)
        self.sem_out = outconv(64, 2)
        self.ins_out = outconv(64, 70)
```

Datasetloader :

```
train_dataset = DataLoaderInstanceSegmentation()
train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=4)
```

Training :

```
for epoch in range(5):    
    for batched in train_dataloader:
        images, sem_labels, ins_labels = batched
        images = Variable(images)
        sem_labels = Variable(sem_labels)
        ins_labels = Variable(ins_labels)
        model.zero_grad()
        sem_predict, ins_predict = model(images)
```

Comment: Without the implementation of the layers and the dataset, I can only assume `inconv(3, 64` has a size of `[64, 3, 3, 3]` and is the layer raising the error when computing the `forward`. Could you print out the shape of `images`? Is it `4, 4, 1024, 2048`? If so, we will need the implementation details of your dataset.

Comment: Thanks @Ivan. Yeah, the shape is  4, 4, 1024, 2048. I think I found the solution and I will post it here. Your explanation really helped me to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. After removing the alpha channel code is working fine

```
        # data = np.array(Image.open(img_path))
        # label_seg = np.array(Image.open(seg_mask_path))
        # label_ins = np.array(Image.open(ins_mask_path))
        data =  self.to_tensor(Image.open(img_path).convert('RGB'))
        label_seg =  self.to_tensor(Image.open(seg_mask_path).convert('L'))
        label_ins =  self.to_tensor(Image.open(ins_mask_path).convert('L'))
```